# Node async await not waiting

Tags: node.js, async-await

When I run the below code and remove the setTimeout all the methods run asynchronously even with the await. Any ideas why the await does not wait.

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({ path: "./config/.env" });
const { setTimeout } = require("timers/promises");

const module1 = require("./utils/module1");
const module2 = require("./utils/module2");
const module3 = require("./utils/module3");

const run = async () => {
  await module1.import();
  await setTimeout(60000);
  await module2.import();
  await setTimeout(120000);
  await module3.import();
};

run();
```

Example of a module:

```
exports.import = async () => {
 //do something
}
```

Comment: What does `.import()` do?

Comment: We have no idea because the issue is with code you're not showing.

Comment: Every import method looks like this

exports.import = async () => { ...}

Comment: The issue is with `//do something`. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: So I guess I am not properly awaiting something in //do something as I am suppose to?

Comment: That would be my guess too.

Comment: @ask4you the question states that `setTimeout()` works fine, but removing it creates an issue

Comment: @ask4you they are using [`timers/promises`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timerspromisessettimeoutdelay-value-options).

Comment: Okay thanks I think I see the issue, I am using the readline module in the module1.import and that does not return a proper Promise. Appreciate the help here.

Comment: @robertklep can you do an answer that states the import does not return a proper Promise? Thanks again.

Comment: It should rather be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @robertklep stated in the comments the problem is inside the actual method of the module.

Nothing was properly awaited inside the first method causing the second method to kick off.

Specifically I was incorrectly using readline and had to change the code as follows:

instead of

```
rl.on()
```

use

```
for await (const line of rl) { }
```